# JavaScript undefined variable detection: typeof==="undefined" vs double exclamation

Tags: javascript, boolean, undefined, typeof

Common practice when checking whether a variable is undefined in JavaScript is as follows:

```
var isUndefined=(typeof variableName==="undefined");
```

I've recently come across the use of two exclamation symbols to determine the same logic:

```
var isUndefined=!!variableName;
```

---

Is it safe to use these methods interchangeably?
Are both equally compatible across browsers?

Is there any reason why one shouldn't use the "!!" method?  (It seems more concise and easy to read)

Comment: `!!variableName` will throw a reference error if `variableName` truly doesn't exist (i.e. no `var variableName` statement) . `typeof variableName` won't throw such an error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yeah, removed my comment. +1 to yours :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it safe to use these methods interchangeably?

No. Details below, but they're not interchangeable even if you remove one of the `!` from your second example (with two of them, it will be `true` for `undefined`, which isn't what you seem to want from the name of the variable you're assigning to). But that's not the only issue.

> Are both equally compatible across browsers?

Yes. Each of them works reliably across browsers. But see above: They *reliably* don't do the same thing.

> Is there any reason why one shouldn't use the "!!" method?

Yes, `!` *(again, not `!!`)* gives the same result for `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `""`, and `false` as it does for `undefined`.

Details:

When you do

```
var isUndefined = typeof variableName==="undefined";
```

*(the `()` are unnecessary)*, you're doing a very specific test for `undefined`. It will only be `true` for `undefined`.

In contrast, when you do

```
var isUndefined = !variableName;
```

you're not testing for `undefined`, you're testing for *any falsey value*. The falsey values are the ones I listed earlier (`0`, `NaN`, `null`, `""`, `false`, and `undefined`). The result will be `true` for any of them.

Now, if you're expecting (for instance) to get a non-`null` object reference or `undefined`, the `!` test is just fine. But if you really need to know whether something is `undefined`, specifically, you want the `typeof` test.

Also, as [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) pointed out in a comment on the question, the `!` test will throw a `ReferenceError` if the variable isn't defined at all (as opposed to being defined but having the value `undefined`), because it tries to read the *value* of the variable. The `typeof` test is safe if you're not sure whether the variable exists at all, because it doesn't try to read its value.